# What does serialized method invocation mean?

Tags: java, serialization

I am reading a book on JPA and EJB and it has a line there stating:

"Singleton session beans can use container-managed or bean-managed concurrency. The default is container-managed, which corresponds to a write lock on all business methods. *All business method invocations are serialized so that only one client can access the bean at any given time.* The actual implementation of the synchronization process is vendor-specific."

What does it mean by method invocation being serialized and why does that guarantee only one client can access the bean at any given time?

Comment: Here, "serialized" is synonymous to "sequential" order of invocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "serialized" they mean "done one at a time" (so don't get that confused with Object Serialization).

Each Singleton Session Bean has a single lock associated with it that can be used by one client at a time. So if you are using the Singleton Session Bean and have the write lock, I can't use it and must wait. Once you release your lock, I will (presumably) grab it and be able to use it, making anybody else who wants to use it wait until I release the lock.

**Edit**: I found a pretty good explanation of [Singleton Session Bean locks and how/when to use them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipsz/index.html).